# how can i delete child values while deleting parent value?

Tags: mysql

i have one table questions where in i am adding question with parent_id = 0 are the parent question and question with parent_id (the parent_id will be same as the id of parent question) are called child question.

this is my table.

```
id   parent_id   question
1      0         what is computer ?
2      1         Device
3      1         Machine
```

i have tried this but no success.

```
DELETE FROM questions WHERE id = 1
AND parent_id = id
```

how can i delete parent question along with its child question?

Comment: you can use OR condition:-
DELETE FROM questions WHERE id = 1 OR parent_id = 1

Comment: Oh thanks a lot it works. its pretty simple.

Comment: If you delete Device, and its parent, then Machine will become orphaned. Is that what you want?

Comment: @JayHardia oops doesn't seen your comment. Just slowly typing the answer and unintentionally ignored your comment which already answered the question.

Comment: @Strawberry i can't stop laughing after reading your comment ;). Most probably he is just giving an example.

Comment: Also, what about multiple levels? Is this a one-level schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this query

```
DELETE FROM questions WHERE id = 1 OR parent_id = id
```

Because `And` query will work only when both conditions match. You need to use `OR` in your case.